# Make Intellij Idea see Phaser library

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, plugins, phaser-framework

I am working with Phaser library in Intellij Idea. I would like my IDE to be able to show me possibilities when I type. How can I do that? For example if I type :

```
jumpButtonUp = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.U);
```

I would like IDE to show me all options of the ending. One of which is `UP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use IntelliJ IDEA, but based [the documentation for Configuring JavaScript Libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-javascript-libraries.html), it's possible to do this via the Ultimate edition.

There's a [Configuring a custom JavaScript library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#configure) section, which begins with the following:

> 1. Open the Settings / Preferences Dialog [...] by choosing File | Settings for Windows and Linux or IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for macOS. Expand the Languages and Frameworks node, and then click Libraries under JavaScript.
> 2. The JavaScript. Libraries page that opens shows a list of all the already available libraries. Click Add.